# API Request Returns Two Objects: How Do I Separate State in Redux with One Reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux

I have an API call, that is returning two objects: data and pageOutput.

```
{
data: "[{"title":["Travis Jackson HOF 1931 W517 # 12 - SGC 50"],"image":["https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFg5NzY=/z/uU8AAOSwMtdd3ZXo/$_1.JPG"],"itemURL":["https://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?ff3=2&toolid=10044&campid=5338164673&customid=vintagebaseball&lgeo=1&vectorid=229466&item=133253226463"]"
pageOutput: "{"pageNumber":["1"],"entriesPerPage":["100"],"totalPages":["2"],"totalEntries":["194"]}"
}
```

I have a reducer that is fetching the data from my API and storing data in a a state called 'baseball' like this.  Note it is just storing the 'data' piece from my API call.

```
const baseballReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INIT_BLOGS":
      return action.data;

export const initializeBaseball = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const baseballCards = await baseballService.getAll();
    dispatch({
      type: "INIT_BLOGS",
      data: JSON.parse(baseballCards.data)
    });
  };
};
```

I need to get the pageOutput into a separate state.  Now i know that i could create a separate page reducer, make a call to the api and store that pageOutput data in a new state.  However, i think that it would be bad practice to make two different calls to the API?

Is there a better way?  I was thinking of just storing all of the data (including the pageOutput) in the baseball state, but then I'm not sure if this is best practice or not, especially considering that I have a Pagination control that needs the updated active page to requery the database.  Hope this is clear enough--happy to provide any additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to make two api calls as you already have all data available in a single api call.

Basically you can:

- Have two reducers listening to the same dispatched action, each reducer receiving a different portion of the total api response by destructuring the payload to the relevant property (data / pageOutput)
- Dispatch two separate actions altogether, one for each reducer.

It doesn't really matter to the app which one you use, so imo it comes down to personal taste.

If you have control over the backend api, I would probably handle pagination a bit differently. Pagination state can be handled fully at the client, and the api would just respond to the client's request (limit / offset - or pageNr, perPage query parameters depending on your taste).
Even though you could therefore return meta data in the api response, you wouldn't need to depend on the api response to manage your state (frontend state change from page1 -> page2 would depend on clicking page2 and configurations defined by the client, not on the response of the api).

Comment: I've done option one a couple times. I needed different parts of the state based on a single call. So I dispatch one action, and then on the return from the api, return another action that is then handled by two reducers. Each one pulls out the part that it needs and stores it accordingly. The key is to then document that the action is handled in two reducers.

Comment: Thanks Trace--i'm going to work on these suggestions.  Much appreciated.  I think i understand what you are saying on pagination however i'm working with the eBay api, which only alllows 100 items returned in one query, thus there is a requirement to make additional calls past that limit.